# how to update multiple documents without id in solr database?

Tags: solr

I have 1.000.000 records in my solr database.
I want to update all records without unique key id,
 but I get error unique key is required! 
my solr document is :

```
  {
  id = 001, 
  name="Joe", 
  city = [Hyderabad], 
  phone = [9848022337]
  }
```

Here is my code.

```
  //Preparing the Solr client 

  //Preparing the Solr document 

  SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();  

  Map map=new HashMap();
  map.put("set","Ahmet");
  doc.addField("name", map);

  // or adding id list 
  // List ids = new ArrayList();
 // doc.addField("id",ids); 


  updateRequest.add( doc );  
  UpdateResponse rsp = updateRequest.process(Solr);
```

how can I do that, any alternative?

```
similar sql is update tableName set name="ahmet"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Any update in Solr must reference the `uniqueKey` of the existing document - there is no functionality like update by query or similar to `UPDATE foo SET bar = 'baz' WHERE field = 'spam';`. The `uniqueKey` field is what defines if a new document is created or the old one is overwritten.

In your example it seems you have an `id` field that is unique, but if that's not the case, you can [configure Solr to assign a unique id to each document when it's added to the index](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#UUID_techniques). You'll then have to reference that id when updating the existing document.

Comment: I have unique id but I want to update all records, any alternative please

Comment: Retrieve the records and update them one by one by referencing their ids.